# calculate differences between two time in minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to calculate differences between two time eg(server time=04:30 pm and `<p id="orderTime">02:30 pm</p>`) and return it in minutes such as 90 minutes using jquery and javascript. The server time and order time is in 12 hour format not in 24h.

Comment: Will it always be in a `HH:mm am` format?

Comment: How is the server time returned? A string? A JSON formatted datetime? Is it stored in a variable? Can you show the code that retrieves it?

Comment: the time is in HH:mm am/pm format and it should return in minutes 00:60 / 60 minutes

Comment: Matt Johnson, I want the time in 12 hours format not in 24 hours

Comment: The server time I simply use the var CurrentDate=new Date();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee they always will be of that format, then here is a straightforward solution:

```
function humanReadableToMinutes(time)
{
    var parts = time.split(/ |:/);

    return (parts[2] == 'pm' * 12 * 60) 
        + parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 60 
        + parseInt(parts[1], 10);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aYwux/2/

Explanation:

1. By `var parts = time.split(/ |:/);` we're splitting `02:30 pm` into 3 parts: `02`, `30`, `pm`.
2. `return (parts[2] == 'pm' * 12 * 60) + parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 60 + parseInt(parts[1], 10);` contains of 3 operands:

   ```
   * (parts[2] == 'pm' * 12 * 60) --- adds additional 12 hours if it's "pm"
   * parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 60 - takes hours fraction extracted and converts it to minutes
   * parseInt(parts[1], 10) - minutes fraction
   ```

PS: this solution doesn't take care of `12am` and `12pm` accurately, so it's a homework for the OP

Comment: Can you please explain me about your codes. Because I like to try to understand it

Comment: Btw, I'd like to hear the criticism from the downvoter :-)

Comment: @gjman2: is it clear enough now?

Comment: @gjman2: see the PS part :-)